# Fill a 2d array of pointers with pointers to structs in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, memory-address

I have a 2 dimensional array of pointers:

```
typedef struct Cell{
   Position p;
   unsigned int value;
} Cell;

typedef struct Position{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
} Position;

int size = 4;
Cell ***cells = malloc(sizeof(Cell**) * size);
int i,j;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cells[i] = malloc(sizeof(Cell*) * size);
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        cells[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is fill this array with pointers to cells, and initialize these cells to contain the value 0 like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        Position p = {i,j};
        Cell c = {p, 0};
        cells[i][j] = &c; //This doesn't work
    }
}
```

As you can already tell, writing the address of c into the pointer cells[i][j] is less than ideal, since every pointer now points to the same address. However I don't know how to fill this array with pointers pointing to individual addresses.

I tried something like this:

```
cells[i][j]->value = 0;
```

which of course also doesn't work. Can anyone give me a hint on how I can solve my problem?

Comment: `cells[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(Cell));` That already sets the entry with a pointer to a struct. Later on you should just be using that pointer. `*(cells[i][j]) = c` will copy the `c` struct contents into the struct pointed to by the array entry.

Comment: "_Can anyone give me a hint on how I can solve my problem?_" - I'm sure someone can if you can describe the problem in more detail - work on describing the problems you are facing. It's a super important skill. It's perhaps more important than being able to solve it yourself. It you can't describe it for others, how can you solve it yourself?

Comment: As I said several times in your other question, you can't assign `&c` to the cells, because those pointers become invalid. You're also creating a memory leak, since you're overwriting the pointers that pointed to the memory created with `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say `cells[i][j]->value = 0;` doesn't work, I believe it should.

This should work to set all the members.

```
Cell ***cells = malloc(sizeof(Cell**) * size);
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cells[i] = malloc(sizeof(Cell*) * size);
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        cells[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
        cells[i][j]->p.x = i;
        cells[i][j]->p.y = j;
        cells[i][j]->value = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten your answer but I see no obvious reason to do that many allocations unless `sizeof(Cell) * size * size` is large enough to make a single allocation fail (but allocating smaller parts doesn't). I suggest doing one allocation only which gives a few benefits. In no particular order:

- Faster allocation in most cases.
- Faster access to the elements that will be tightly packed and therefore be more cache friendly.
- Easier memory management - there is only one pointer to check and `free`.
- Less total memory allocated than when allocating memory for a lot of pointers.

Example 1 - Make `cells` a pointer to the first of `size` number of elements of `Cell[size]`.

```
// one allocation:
Cell (*cells)[size] = malloc( size * sizeof *cells );

if(cells == NULL) exit(1); // check for allocation failure

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        cells[i][j].p.y = i;
        cells[i][j].p.x = j;
        cells[i][j].value = 0;
    }
}
```

Example 2 - Make `cells` a pointer to a single `Cell[size][size]`:

```c
// one allocation:
Cell (*cells)[size][size] = malloc( sizeof *cells );

if(cells == NULL) exit(1); // check for allocation failure

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        (*cells)[i][j].p.y = i;
        (*cells)[i][j].p.x = j;
        (*cells)[i][j].value = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        Position p = {i,j};
        Cell c = {p, 0};
        cells[i][j] = &c; //This doesn't work
    }
    // to this line, 'c' & 'p' will be freed since it was allocated on stack not heap.
    // 'c' & 'p' will be freed when program gets out of 2nd for loop, so either you can
    // use memcpy to copy 'c' into cells[i][j] or use malloc to allocate 'c' and 'p'
}
```